# Why does the electromagnetic tensor in component form coincide with the differential-geometric definition of a $2$-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, differential-forms, vector-fields, electromagnetism

From physics classes, I understand the electromagnetic field strength tensor to be defined as
$$F^{\mu\nu}=\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu \;,$$
where $\partial^\mu$ is the partial derivative (which I understand to be a vector) and $A^\mu$ is the electromagnetic vector potential (which I understand to be a vector *field*, the photon field upon quantisation).

From differential geometry, I understand a $2$-form to be an antisymmetric $(0,2)$-tensor field, namely an antisymmetric multilinear map
$$\omega:\Gamma(TM)\times\Gamma(TM)\longrightarrow C^{\infty}(M)$$

where $\Gamma(TM)$ is the set of vector fields on $M$.

Here's my problem: I have seen in many places that "The electromagnetic field strength tensor is a $2$-form". However, I am struggling to see how the definition of the field strength tensor that I know, and the definition of a $2$-form that I know, fit together.

1. A $2$-form takes as its arguments two vector *fields*, not two vectors. $A^\mu$ is a vector field, but as far as I understand, $\partial^\nu$ is a vector (an object that takes a function and differentiates it), not a vector *field*. As such, it feels wrong to write the field strength tensor as *something like*
   \begin{align}
   F:\Gamma(TM)\times\Gamma(TM)&\longrightarrow C^{\infty}(M)\\
   (\partial^\mu,A^\mu)&\mapsto F(\partial^\mu,A^\mu).
   \end{align}
   The above is obviously sloppy but I suppose what I'm saying is that **it isn't clear to me that the above definition of the field strength in component form coincides in any way with the definition of a $2$-form.**
2. I feel uneasy about my understanding of these objects in differential-geometric terms: **If a derivative is a vector in differential geometry, and a tangent vector takes as its argument a function $f\in C^\infty(M)$, how/why are the derivatives in the above definition of the field strength tensor acting on the vector field $A^\mu$?**

Comment: It may help to write down the potential one form explicitly: $A=-Vdt+A_1dx^1+A_2dx^2+A_3dx^3$, from which we can read off the covariant tensor components. Then compute $dA=F$ directly

Comment: If you're thinking of the derivative $\partial^\nu$ as a "vector," then of course it's the vector field $\partial/\partial x^\nu$ on the coordinate chart. The summation convention is messed up because your indices should actually be lower indices.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah - there's a source of confusion for me. You're saying $\partial_\mu$ is a vector *field*, not a vector? I suppose evaluating the derivative at a specific $p\in M$ makes $(\partial_\mu)_p$ a *vector*? Also as an aside, i've seen $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\mu}=\partial_\mu(f\circ x^{-1})$, ie $\partial_\mu$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ aren't always equivalent (?) - does that apply here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**the first question**

The thing is that it is a little bit sloppy to say that $F^{\mu \nu}$ is a tensor. It is a **coordinate function** of a tensor. The tensor, or, in this case, a 2-form, is

$$ F =\frac{1}{2} F_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu. $$

*(Einstein summation convention is used.)*

Here $dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu = \frac{1}{2} (dx^\mu \otimes dx^\nu - dx^\nu \otimes dx^\mu)$ is **antisymmetric product** or **exterior product**. The main property of this is that it is antisymmetric, so you can neglect explicit expression via tensor products.

F acts on a pare of vector fields $(v,w)$ as

$$ F(v,w)=F_{\mu \nu} (dx^\mu v) (dx^\nu w) = F_{\mu \nu} v^\mu w^\nu.  $$

Thus the answer for the first question in some coordinate system is

$$ (v,w) \mapsto F_{\mu \nu} v^\mu w^\nu. $$

**the second question**

I hope to clarify this place, but I am not sure if it will be satisfying. Derivatives are indeed tangent vectors, but $A^\mu$ is not a vector field, just as $F^{\mu\nu}$ is not a tensor, it is again a **coordinate function** of a vector field. And in this sense, it is not a problem that some vector acts on a function, though it has label $\mu$.

However, to understand this place better you should think about $A$ as about 1-form rather than vector field $A_\mu dx^\mu$. For forms (of any order) you can define **exterior derivative** $d$. It maps $p$-forms to $(p+1)$-forms. I'll write here how it acts in some coordinate system. Suppose you have a $p$-form $w=w_{\mu_1 \ldots \mu_p} dx^{\mu_1} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^{\mu_p}$, then:

$$ dw = \partial_{\mu_0} w_{\mu_1 \ldots \mu_p} dx^{\mu_0} \wedge dx^{\mu_1} \wedge \ldots dx^{\mu_p}  $$

Having this, you can easily see that if $A$ is a $1$-form $A=A_\mu dx^\mu$, then

$$ d A = \partial_\nu A_\mu dx^\nu \wedge dx^\mu =\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\nu A_\mu - \partial_\mu A_\nu) dx^\nu \wedge dx^\mu=F.$$

If you are interested in details, I would recommend you to read "Gauge Fields, Knots
And Gravity" by John Baez and Javier P. Muniain. It has a good elementary introduction about manifolds, vector fields, forms and all of this. Though it is not completely rigorous, it is more than enough to understand the language.